# django how do i mix an order_by and a get in a listview url?

Tags: django

So i want to create:

select * from Post where Post.is_chosen = true order_by create_date

and i want this to occur in the urls.py (that is, not have to define anything, just stick it in the ListView parameters)

How do i do this?

I currently have:

```
url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Post.objects.get(is_chosen = True).order_by('-pub_date')[:20],
    context_object_name='latest_post_list',
    template_name='posts/index.html')),
```

but this has an error - i cannot call order_by on the return object of the "get" This makes sense, but how can i do what i want?

I am open to calling the command from a defined function if it is impossible to do in the url definition!

UPDATE: ARGH I am an idiot.

"get" only returns one item, so of course "order_by" won't work on it. I use filter instead now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) say, use `.filter()` instead.